# Loading json data and updating view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using OnsenUI with AngularJS to build a searching app, on page1 the user enters data to search for, when pressing search button page1 is pushed in the stack and a get request is fired in background to get the requested data.

I used a global variable to store data obtained from the service and `$watch` to watch any changes in the data and update the corresponding scope variable with the new value.

app.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var x;
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['onsen.directives']);
    app.factory('pageService',['$http', function ($http) {
        var fetchedData;
        return {
            start: function(){
                $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'}).
                success(function(data, status, header, config){
                    console.log('Success !');
                    console.log('Data Name : ' + data[0].name);
                    x = data[0];
                    return data;
                }).
                error(function(data, status, header, config){
                    console.log('fail !');
                    return status;
                })
            },
            getData: function(){
                return fetchedData;
            }
        };
    }]);
    app.controller('page1Ctrl',function($scope,pageService){
        $scope.goToPage2 = function(){
            $scope.x = pageService.start();
            $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage("page2.html");
        }
    });
    app.controller('page2Ctrl',function($scope,pageService){
        $scope.$watch('x',function(newValue, oldValue){
            console.log("x = " + newValue);
            $scope.x = x;
        });
    });

})();
```

index.html body

```
<body>
  <ons-screen>
      <ons-page class="center" ng-controller="page1Ctrl">
    <ons-navigator title="Page 1">
        <div class="center">
          <h1>Pharmy</h1>
            <ons-text-input ng-model="medicine" placeholder="Enter Medicine Name" style="display:block; width:100%;" id="test"></ons-text-input>
            <div style="position:relative">
                <ons-text-input ng-model="location" placeholder="Enter Location" style="display:block; width:100%; margin-top:10px;"></ons-text-input>
                <ons-icon icon="search" style="position:absolute;right:10px;top:5px;"></ons-icon>
            </div>
            <ons-button ng-click="goToPage2()"
                        style="width:10%; margin-top:10px;">
                <ons-icon icon="search"></ons-icon>
            </ons-button>
        </div>
    </ons-navigator>
          </ons-page>
  </ons-screen>
</body>
```

and page2.html

```
<ons-page class="center" ng-controller="page2Ctrl">
    <ons-navigator-toolbar
        title="Page 2">     
    </ons-navigator-toolbar>
    <h2>Page 2</h2>
    <textarea id="test2" ng-model="x"></textarea>
</ons-page>
```

What am I missing there ? why the text area doesn't update ?

Comment: you can create another service rather than having a global variable and then use this service to get value from one controller to other or if you want to avoid the fuss, you can make use of $rootScope

Comment: already tried that, the problem is not in the local variable as I guess.

Comment: the watch will check only those values which are in scope so maybe you doing something wrong over there

Comment: maybe you're right, but I tried using service scope variable `fetchedData` and put `pageService.getData()`  in watch statement, but didn't work either.

Comment: If you using service then no need to have a watch, you can simply emit/broadcast the variable and then catch that in the other controller using $scope.$on method

Comment: Thanks @V31, it worked ! Please,add your answer to mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Angular Services in order to avoid $scope.$watch method. and simply $emit/$broadcast the variable. In the second controller catch the variable using $scope.$on and it will work

[More Documentation on Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

[Documentation on $emit and $broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: added Documentation links as well for future use